# How to get a copy of the original json row for matches after registerTempTable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Code:

rddWithJsonData:

```
[
       {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
       {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
       {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"} 
]

sqlCtx.read.json(rddWithJsonData).registerTempTable("myTable")
val df = sqlCtx.sql("select firstName from myTable where lastName='Doe'")
```

Current:

df.show()

```
+---------------------+
|  firstName          |
+---------------------+
|  John               |
+---------------------+
```

What I need:

```
+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|  firstName          |  Original Json Row                     |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|  John               |  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}|
+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

How to get the original json data row(that matched) along with the filtered table row?

The results are needed in a DataFrame.

Comment: What do you mean by _the original json_? JSON string used as an input? Parsed structure?

Comment: @Sahil: Where is your filter? And what does "mySqlQuery" mean?

Comment: @MartinSenne: Updated

Comment: @zero323 Added an example

Comment: @Sahil: First the original JSON is not kept (and not.available). Why do you need that? If you have the full row, you can write that as json via `df.write.json(...)`.

Comment: @MartinSenne Thanks +1 and AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is a little vague, try to filter and use "!" to invert that filter, like

```
inputDf.filter( df("lastName") === "Doe" ) // fetches matches
inputDf.filter( !df("lastName") === "Doe" ) // fetches no matching rows
```

or SQL as follows

```
val df = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE lastName='Doe'")
```